# How do I easily generate many weighted crosstabs with more than two variables?

Tags: r, survey

I have a large survey for which I need to generate a set of tables for all items in the questionnaire, cross-tabbed by city/location *and* a set of demographic variables. I.e. within each city, I want to find the proportion of responses to a given question by each demographic. I need these to sum to 1 within each city's demographic. The data is a mix of categorical and numerical data. This gives some idea of what the data look like, including weights for each observation:

```
library(dplyr)
n = 30

df <- data.frame(city = sample(c("New York", "Chicago", "Boston"), n, replace = TRUE),
                 gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE),
                 religion = sample(c("Protestant", "Catholic", "Jewish"), n, replace = TRUE),
                 weights = runif(n, min = 0.1, max = 2.0),
                 q1 = sample(c("good", "bad", "okay"), n, replace = TRUE),
                 q2 = sample(c("always", "sometimes", "never"), n, replace = TRUE),
                 q3 = sample(c(1:6), n, replace = TRUE))
```

I know there should be some way to do this using weighted counts and proportions within `dplyr`, but haven't had much luck. Using a `for` loop with `wtd.table` doesn't work because it only allows for two variables at a time. Would really appreciate any suggestions for how to easily tabulate many weighed proportions using more than one crossing variable.

```
df %>%
  group_by(city, religion, gender)  %>%
  count(names(df)[5:7], wt = weights) %>%
  summarise(weighted.mean())
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the example shared?

Comment: Have you looked at the `questionr` package? The `wtd.table` function allows you to specify subgroups.